kubeadm pulling the required images offline
I am trying to pull kubeadm necessary images; however, I can not connect to the repository due to restriction on my organization internet
root@bi:~# kubeadm config images pull --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.31.1": failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.31.1: Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "\n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>\n<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.31.1</code> from this server.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n"
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

Is there any way I can pull them manually? I mean telling the kubeadm to use the files I have downloaded previously.

You can try to save your image, copy files to the Node/Server and then load it to image with tag. With Docker or with some other tools.
But if kubeadm cannot do the pull, then you cannot it doo too.
https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/save/
https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/load/
